# XSS and Friendly Urls

Tags: url, xss, sql-injection

According to your own experience, are friendly urls secure?

XSS always work through urls with parameters, but since friendly urls have no parameters, is there any way xss can work with friendly urls and how we can avoid it?

Just want to hear your comments.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The two concepts — URL format and security vulnerabilties — are completely independent.

You can write code with security vulnerabilities with both URL formats.

Neither URL format will implicitly make code safe.

This applies to both XSS vulnerabilities and SQL injection vulnerabilities. These are two different types of security bugs, but they both are caused by *your code*, not by one URL format or the other.

XSS does *not* work only through URLs with request parameters. XSS flaws occur when you display data without html-encoding it, so if the data contains something that looks like HTML markup (including Javascript `<script>` tags), then an attacker can manipulate the HTML rendering.